# What happens to Mephiles after you defeat Solaris and blow out his flame?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog-2006

Today, my brother was playing Sonic 2006, and he beat it. At the end, it says what happens to everybody but Mephiles. Where did he go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: when Elise blows out Solaris's flame at the end,

> they did it in the past, so everything that had happened in the future never actually happened.